# java gui while adding jpanel of one class to jframe of another class

Tags: user-interface

I have added a button in a panel of first class.
When I add that panel to jframe of another class it does not show any button. It shows empty jframe. There is no error.

```
ClassName obj=new ClassName ();
JFrameName.add(obj);
```

Everything seems fine no error or anything.
I have also seen other similar question on panel but nothing is helpful.

Plzzzz any simple example with output shown will be gr8.
P.s i am using netBeans

Comment: The fact they are in separate classes shouldn't matter. What layout is your JFrames content pane?

Comment: I have tried all layouts border, grid and others

Comment: You're going to have to post some code then. Note that you cannot have a component in more than one container if that is what you are trying to do.